# How to merge cells (Rowwise or columnwise) in wpf datagrid?

Tags: wpf

is there anyway to Merge cells (Rowwise or column wise) like winforms DataGrid.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid