# Dynamic row and column span in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm working on a new project where the design calls for dynamic rows and columns displayed in some form of grid.  I think I can accomplish this very hackishly using the plain ol' Grid, but it seems like it should be possible using a "real" grid.[image: mockup]

In my mockup, I circled the tricky bit in red.  Under column 1, I have effectively 2 columns of data.  The problem is the fact that my data in column 1 can span multiple rows.  And the fact that column one is really two pseudo columns and each one can span a different number of rows independently.  Note: the data is fake and inconsequential.  I'm open to ideas for a good implementation.  I can fall back to the Grid and do this all in code behind, I'm open to purchasing a datagrid that may have more power than the DataGrid and my absolute **last** resort/preference is to restructure this format to something a little more doable.

Thank you for any ideas you can provide.

Comment: Actually, I think what I'm trying to do is really called "merging" cells.  I found a topic on SO discussing it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276873/how-to-merge-cells-rowwise-or-columnwise-in-wpf-datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most commercial WPF DataGrid implementations handle hierarchical data like this.  For example, [Telerik's DataGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/gridview.aspx#hierarchy) (part of RadControls for WPF) supports hierarchical data in multiple formats.

Typically, the default styling is a bit different than yours above, but can be adapted to that format via styling.

Comment: Actually, I think what I'm trying to do is really called "merging" cells.  I found a topic on SO discussing it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276873/how-to-merge-cells-rowwise-or-columnwise-in-wpf-datagrid

I may still go with a commercial tool though.

Comment: @billb: It depends- treating this as a hierarchy will provide the same effect, but has MANY advantages (when using commercial grids), since you can also do things like total and handle grouping by category + subcategory automatically, etc.

Comment: Direct link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid