# horizontal and vertical columns at the same time in a wpf datagrid in c#

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I need a special datagrid with horizontal and vertical columns at the same time in a wpf datagrid  using c# .
I mean 4 columns vertical and then a column horizontal like below

```
    col1  |  col2   |  col3  |  Col4
     ....    ....      ....     ...
col5  ...............................
     ....    ....      ....     ...
     ...............................
```

Is this possible ? i wish i wouldn't force to produce a new class for the datagrid from scratch

Comment: [`ColumnSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan(v=vs.110).aspx) ([tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-column-row-span/))?

Comment: It's about DATAGRID not grid

Comment: You can still use the *term*. What you want is called either *column span* or *cell merge* ("vertical columns" sounds confusing). [Click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4839099/1997232), [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17202389/1997232), should be more.

Comment: I really appreciate about your guidances , I'm not going to use a commercial datagrid so the socond link you have provided is the most useful article i got till now. the second link gave me some ideas but it doesn't fit 100% of my case. thank you again