# Merge Cells in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to create a WPF datagrid that spans over multiple rows in one column. Like this:

```
+-------+----------------+
| Name  | Attributes     |
+-------+----------------+
|       | Horse Power    |
| BMW   +----------------+
|       | Color          |
+-------+----------------+
|       | Weight         |
| Ford  +----------------+
|       | Color          |
+-------+----------------+
```

How can the following code be changed to get it done?

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" />
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="Attributes" />
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use a `DataGrid` for this?  This looks simple enough that you should be able to do it in a `ListView` more easily, with customized ListViewItems.

Comment: I think a ListView would work too. The real thing has more columns, they will be colored on click of specific cells and so on...

Comment: I'm not the biggest fan of the `ListView` myself, but for the customizations that you're looking for, I think it would be the preferable choice.  I've found that the `DataGrid` (even 3rd party `DataGrid` controls) aren't easily able to do things like "multi-row column cells".

Answer (score 11):

Try use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. I created sample test class for databinding

```
public class Test
{

    public Test(string name, string attribute1, string attribute2)
    {
        Name = name;
        Attributes = new Attribute(attribute1, attribute2);
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Attribute Attributes { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{

    public Attribute(string attribute1, string attribute2)
    {
        Attribute1 = attribute1;
        Attribute2 = attribute2;
    }

    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

And a datagrid in xaml

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name"  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Attributes"  >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Path=Attributes.Attribute1}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                            <Line Grid.Row="1" Stroke="Black" Stretch="Fill" X2="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=Attributes.Attribute2}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,3,3,3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

And fill it in code-behind

```
List<Test> list = new List<Test>();
//populate list with your data here
dataGrid1.DataContext = list;
```

Comment: This works but note that once you use DataGridTemplateColumn Copy/Paste no longer works across rows or columns.

Comment: What if the number of attributes are dynamic, sometimes 2, sometimes 4 ? How can it be rendered ?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to implement a solution that does what you want with three levels of grouping with one small issue, in that that the Group Headers scroll horizontally with the data.

```
    <Style x:Key="GroupItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Border BorderThickness="0">
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Border BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="150">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" >
                                            </ContentPresenter>
                                        </Grid>

                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And the Grid:

```
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinRowHeight="25" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                    <!-- First Group -->
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>

                    <!-- Second Group -->
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>

                    </GroupStyle>

                    <!-- Third Group -->
                    <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score -2):

Another helpful article on the subject is http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/90371ed3-c0f7-49eb-ba2d-9d1f2c9b14e2/?Grid%20Control%20in%20WPF:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="First Button" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="Second Button" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="Thired Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
    <Button x:Name="btn4" Content="Fourth Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
    <Button x:Name="btn5" Content="Fifth Button" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Button x:Name="btn6" Content="Six Button" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Notice the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` attributes.

Comment: This appears to be about the layout grid, not the DataGrid