# How to merge two cell in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm writing spreadsheet based on wpf datagrid, and I want to add functionality like merging two cells (excel like). Can anyone tell me if it's possible in datagrid at runtime and if so, how to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid