# Is it possible to merge the cells (rows) in a data grid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a data grid in WPF application having 2 columns A and B.

"Column A" has different names, whereas "column B" has a default name. Is it possible to merge the rows of columns B so that the word "Alphabets" will be the default name for all the rows in "column B".

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Greetings! Please post some code, what have you tried?

Comment: I've never done it, so I don't know if it is really possible. But i can't see how would that be useful. Wouldn't be better to use the datagrid grouping built-in function?

Comment: See following posting : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-us/bbda3e63-30f2-47f1-ae00-2f022796c21e/merge-datagridview-row-and-column-cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Cells in WPF DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: Try use `DataGridTemplateColumn`. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid).