# Problem to make Nested Datagrids From Xml data

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to display some data contained into an xml file with Serialization/Deserialization. I'm actually having issue making the view to display the content of the XML file.

What i'm trying to do is actually to make a grid layout looking to something like this:

[image]

The Xml structure is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Data>
  <Car Title="Audi">
    <Modele>A3</Duration>
  </Car>
  <Car Title="Peugeot">
  </Car>
  <4x4 Title="Audi">
    <Options Number="1">
      <Technology Title="Moteur">
      </Technology>
      <Technology Title="Roue">
      </Technology>
    </Options>
    <Options Number="2">
      <Technology Title="Roue">
      </Technology>
      <Technology Title="Moteur">
      </Technology>
    </Options>
   </4x4>
</Data>
```

What i've done actually far from what i want:

```
<WrapPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Cars" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marque" Binding="{Binding Marque}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Modele" Binding="{Binding Modele}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="4x4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Marque" Binding="{Binding Marque}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Options" Binding="{Binding Options}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </StackPanel>
        </WrapPanel>
```

and the complete mapping of the xml file in my code:

```
[KnownType(typeof(Cars))]
[KnownType(typeof(4x4))]
[KnownType(typeof(Options))]
public abstract class DataItem
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Marque{ get; set; }
}

[DataContract ,XmlRoot(ElementName = "Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement("Cars", Type=typeof(Cars))]
    [XmlElement("4x4", Type=typeof(4x4))]
    [DataMember]
    public List<DataItem> Items { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "4x4")]
public class 4x4: DataItem
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Options", Type=typeof(Options))]
    public List<Options> Options{ get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Options")]
public class Options
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Number")]
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Components", Type=typeof(Components))]
    public List<Technology> Technologys { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Cars")]
public class Cars : DataItem
{
    [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public Nullable<int> Modele { get; set; }
}

public class Technology : DataItem
{
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge Cells in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: Well, actually i tried to do something with wrap and Stack Panel to display to gridLayout one below the other but still getting the problem of Options containing another gridLayout.

Comment: @GuillaumeD: Well, you should post some code that demonstrates what you have actually tried when asking a question.

Comment: What classes/models are you deserializing into?

Comment: I edited my question with the total details.