# How Can I merge the same Value in my DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

so I have made an DataGrid, in which I Styled the whole DataGrid with some Templates. Now I wanted to merge every Cell that has the Same Value. I add the data from an SQL Query. Thats my DataGrid XAML Code:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
                    <!--Design kopfzeile-->
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Name="test" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="insideHeader" Background="#353E4A">
                                        <Border x:Name="borderHeader" BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="#4F5C73"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        Margin="2">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </Border>

                                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" Grid.Column="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Width="2" BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#353E4A"
                        Cursor="SizeWE"/>

                                    </Grid>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=toogleButton,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#FA9F34"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#2B2B2B"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="insideHeader" Property="Background" Value="#00336E"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="#4182C6"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>

                    <!--Deaktivieren Des rowheader-->
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>

                    <!--Cellen Design-->
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3E4659"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Border x:Name="insideBorder" Background="#353E4A">
                                        <Border x:Name="BorderCell" BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="#4F5C73"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        Margin="2">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding ElementName=toogleButton,Path=IsChecked}" Value="False">
                                            <Setter TargetName="BorderCell" Property="Background" Value="#0051B0"/>
                                            <Setter TargetName="insideBorder" Property="Background" Value="#00336E"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="BorderCell" Property="Background" Value="#4182C6"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>


                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
```

**What I have already tried** was something like that, with GroupStyles but that didnt work, with that Code nothing happend:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GroupedData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" MinRowHeight="25" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <!-- First Group -->
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>

                <!-- Second Group -->
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>

                </GroupStyle>

                <!-- Third Group -->
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupItemStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

and here the Style for that:

```
<Style x:Key="GroupItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Border BorderThickness="0">
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Border BorderThickness="1" MinWidth="150">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" >
                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                    </Grid>

                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <ItemsPresenter/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The Structure I try to get would look like hat Structure:

[image: Structure]

So why does this Dont work?

Comment: When you say merge, what exactly do you mean? Do you want to remove all duplicates of any DataGrid row with the same value in a given cell? or do you want all DataGrid rows with the same value in a specific cell placed in a separately styled subset of the DataGrid? I'm only assuming the latter because you're attempting to use grouping. And while you show us a lot of your styling, we don't know anything about the structure of the underlying data. I could tell you why your grouping probably doesn't work, but I can't tell if grouping is actually what you're looking for.

Comment: I added a picture of what structure i want to get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge Cells in WPF DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17202389/merge-cells-in-wpf-datagrid)

Comment: @Shrimperator  I Already tried that but that didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments I gather that your issue is specifically, that DataGrid grouping doesn't work for you.

If you want to use DataGrid grouping, you'll have to use a CollectionViewSource, give it a GroupDescription and point the CollectionViewSource to the collection it should use. When binding, you then bind to the CollectionViewSource instead of the actual collection. If the DataGrid has no such GroupDescription, the GroupStyle will be ignored.

eg.

```
<Window.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupedDataViewSource" Source="{Binding GroupedData}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>
```

and to bind to it...

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey = GroupedDataViewSource}}"/>
```

To create a ViewSource in C#:

```
CollectionViewSource myViewSource = new CollectionViewSource { Source = mySource };
myViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("someHeaderNameToGroupBy"));
```

you can then bind to it like you would any other collection.

Comment: How can achieve same using c# code only, no xaml file? in form.designer.cs class

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "form.designer.cs class", but I've edited the answer to explain how to create GrooupDescriptions and ViewSources in C#.